# Proving $F*G(x)=\int G(z-x)dF(x)$ to be the distribution $X+Y$

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X,Y$ be two independent random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{A},P)$ following the distribution functions $F$ and $G$ respectively and consider a random variable $Z=X+Y$.
>   Prove that the distribution function of $Z$ is $F*G(x)=\int G(z-x)dF(x)$.

Since $Z=X+Y$ it is trivial $Y=Z-X$, so the  convolution makes sense. However I do not know what I am suppose to prove.

If I start by defining H as the probability distribution of Z then $\int d H=\int d(F*G(x))$, however I do not know how to proceed.

**Questions:**

How should I solve the question?

How do I prove $H$ to be a distribution?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

For any bounded function $h(x,y)$
\begin{aligned}
E[h(X,Y)]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_x\times\mathbb{R}_y} h(x,y) F(dx)G(dy)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}_x}h(x,y) F(dx)\Big)G(dy)
\end{aligned}
In particular, if $h(x,y)=\mathbb{1}_A(x+y)$ for some measurable $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ you get
\begin{aligned}
E[h(X+Y)]&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}_x}\mathbb{1}_A(x+y) F(dx)\Big)G(dy)\\
&=\int_{\mathbb{R}_y}F(A-y)\,G(dx)
\end{aligned}

Answer (score 1):

If $\ Y\ $ and $\ X\ $ are independent, then $\ \mathbb{P}\left(Y\in A\ \&\ X\in B\,\right)\ =$ $\ \mathbb{P}\left(Y\in A\,\right)\mathbb{P}\left(X\in B\,\right)=\int_AdG(y)\int_BdF(x)\ $, and $\ \mathbb{P}\left((X,Y)\in S\,\right)\ $ $\ = \int\hspace{-0.4em}\int_\limits{S}dG(y)\,dF(x)\ $.  The distribution $\ H\ $ of $\ Z\ $ is given by $\ H(z)=\mathbb{P}\left(X+Y\le z\right)=\mathbb{P}\left((X,Y)\in \left\{(x,y)\left\vert x+y\le z\right.\right\}\,\right)\ $. Thus
\begin{eqnarray}
H(z) &=& \int_\limits{\left\{(x,y)\left\vert x+y\le z\right.\right\}}\hspace{-1.8em}\int dG(y)\,dF(x)\\
&=& \int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty\int_\limits{-\infty}^{z-x}dG(y)\,dF(x)\\
&=& \int_\limits{-\infty}^\infty G(z-x)\,dF(x)\ .
\end{eqnarray}